# How to load multiple models for whole controller in CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In cakephp 2.x we can load multiple models for whole controller

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class PagesController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('model1', 'model2', 'model3', .... );

public function index(){
}

}
?>
```

How to do same on Cakephp 4.x

Answer (score 2):

Use `loadModel()` multiple times in the controller's `beforeFilter()` method.

```php
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $this->loadModel('Model1');
    $this->loadModel('Model2');
    $this->loadModel('Model3');
    // ...
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Controller Callback Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers.html#controller-callback-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Loading Additional Models](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models)**

Comment: Yes i am doing same. just wanted to know if can do in one line. anyway thanks